# How to covert for statement to map or reduce on node js?

Tags: node.js, eslint

I have code as below:

```
const compareTwoObj = (obj1, obj2) => {
  const common = {};
  for (const key of Object.keys(obj2)) {
      if (obj2[key] !== undefined) {
          if (typeof obj1[key] === 'object') {
              common[key] = compareTwoObj(obj1[key], obj2[key]);
          }
          else {
              if (obj1[key] === obj2[key]) {
                  common[key] = obj1[key];
              }
          }
      }
  }
  return common;
}
```

After, I wrote this code on my node js. It's getting error **interator/generators require re-generator run-time** Because of **eslint**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it `.keys` returns an array, you can call `.forEach` on the array instead.

But since you want to work with both the key and the value, consider using `Object.entries` instead, which returns an array of entries (key-value pairs in the form of an array) - you might find it a bit cleaner.

```
const compareTwoObj = (obj1, obj2) => {
    const common = {};
    Object.entries(obj2).forEach(([key, value2]) => {
        if (value2 === undefined) return; // don't do anything this iteration
        const value1 = obj1[key];
        if (typeof value1 === 'object') {
            common[key] = compareTwoObj(value1, value2);
        }
        else if (value1 === value2) {
            common[key] = value1;
        }
    });
    return common;
}
```